# Как разархивировать архив *.pptx?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь распаковать таким образом:

```
import shutil
filename = "Sample.pptx"
extract_dir = "/temps"
archive_format = "pptx"
shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_dir, archive_format)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ValueError: Unknown unpack format 'pptx'

[Посмотрел документацию](https://%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20shutil%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B:), данный тип архива не поддерживается. Может, кто разархивировал/архивировал такой тип файла? Чем пользовались?

Comment: `archive_format = "zip"`

Comment: дак я же не zip разархивирую, а именно pptx

Comment: pptx это и есть zip-архив

Comment: аа.. сорян.. Я Тоже сначала пробовал ZIP, но смотрел через IDE - там не показало, что появилась папка... А она там появилась))) Спасибо)

Comment: pptx - это не тип архива или файла, это просто расширение, просто часть имени фактически. Тип архива (способ архивирования) у pptx и других "новых" типов файлов MS Office (docx, xlsx и т.д.) - zip.